# PowerShell Import-Csv: extract multiple values from a single cell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, import-csv

I have a table which is in the same format as
[image]

There are rows of AD groupnames and I am trying to add the list of users who belong to the group adjacent to it. The problem is that all of the members of the groups are within a single cell and are separated by a de-limiter. Is there any way to tell PowerShell that for each line in the csv, add those users (separated by delimiter) to that group?

```
    $file = Import-Csv "Z:\VM share\outputTEST.csv"    foreach ($line in $file)
   {
    ...
   }
```

Any advice would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but something like that should work:

```
Import-Csv "Z:\VM share\outputTEST.csv" | foreach {

    $groupname = $_.groupname
    $_."members of group" -split(",") | foreach {

        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Members $_
    }
}
```

Comment: According to [this syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh852331(v=wps.630).aspx) the  `-Members` parameter should accept an array of samAccountnames, so no need to add another ForEach.

Comment: Thanks @LotPings just checked the help. It seems that you're right and the second foreach of my solution won't be necessary.